# Active Reports http download not working as intended

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core-webapi, activereports

I'm trying to generate Active Reports (v16) in a Web APi Controller, netcore 6.0. The result in the browser is always "failed" for both types. What am I doing wrong ?

```
       [HttpGet("GetExcelReport")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetExcelReportAsync(string type)
        {
            var stream = GenerateDoc(type, Response);

            await stream.CopyToAsync(Response.Body);
            return new OkResult();
        }
        internal System.IO.Stream GenerateDoc(string type, HttpResponse response)
        {
            using (var reportStream =
                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("App.Reports.Reports.PageReport1.rdlx"
                ))
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(reportStream))
            {
                var rpt = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.PageReport(reader);
                
                IRenderingExtension ri = null;

                if (type == "pdf")
                {
                    ri = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.Page.PdfRenderingExtension();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename=sdfgsdfg-sdfgsdf.pdf");
                }
                else
                {   
                    ri = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Excel.Page.ExcelRenderingExtension();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    Response.Headers.Add("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename=sdfgsdfg-sdfgsdf.xls");
                }

                var output = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Rendering.IO.MemoryStreamProvider();
                rpt.Document.Render(ri, output);
                return output.GetPrimaryStream().OpenStream();
            }
        }
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your thrid-part tool works well and you could get the stream successfully.

You could check `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase` class and you could find all methods to return FileResult:

[image]

For your requirement,you could try this method

```
public virtual FileStreamResult File(Stream fileStream, string contentType, string? fileDownloadName)
```

I tried and the Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way in which I return the file.

```
 [HttpGet("GetExcelReport")]
        public IActionResult GetExcelReportAsync()
        {
            Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(System.Reflection.Assembly));
            using (var reportStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("BFW.Reports.Reports.PageReport1.rdlx"))
                if (reportStream != null)
                {
                    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(reportStream))
                    {
                        var rpt = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.PageReport(reader);

                        IRenderingExtension? re = null;

                        re = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Export.Excel.Page.ExcelRenderingExtension();

                        var output = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Rendering.IO.MemoryStreamProvider();

                        rpt.Document.Render(re, output);

                        return File(output.GetPrimaryStream().OpenStream(), "application/octet-stream", "excelfile.xlsx");
                    }
                }

            return NotFound();
        }
```